# How to calculate the standard errors of the variance components of a mixed model using glmer with a Poisson distribution in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a set of count data, and want to find out how the variance is partitioned among random effects.

Let’s say I counted the number jumps that animals did. In my model, I included (apart from three fixed effects: trial number, species, habitat), two random effects: individual and population. I want to know how much variance in the data is caused by differences between individuals, differences between populations and differences within individuals (i.e. residual variation).

I fitted a generalized mixed model, using the function `glmer` from the package `lme4`:

```r
myModel <- glmer(nrJumps ~ trial + species * habitat + 
    (1|individual) + (1|population), data=myData, 
    family = poisson)
```

The part of the output dealing with the random effects looks like this:

```r
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 individual (Intercept) 4.933e+00 2.2210832
 population (Intercept) 5.243e-07 0.0007241
```

This output does not give the residual variance, as I was used from the outputs of `lmer` models with a Gaussian distribution, see here:

```r
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 individual (Intercept) 4.947e-01 7.034e-01
 population (Intercept) 1.522e-10 1.234e-05
 Residual             1.144e+00 1.069e+00
```

If I correctly understand Nakagawa & Schielzeth 2010 (Biological Reviews), I can calculate the residual variance from my Poisson model using:

*ω · ln(1 / exp(β0) + 1)*

ω being the dispersion of the model, β0 the grand mean.

However, this formula will only result in an average value of variance, but not its standard error. The same for the variances of the two random effects individual and population.

So, my question: Is there a way to calculate the standard errors of both the variances of the random effects and that of the residual variance?

Comment: Estimating a SE doesn't really make sense, because the CI / likelihood profile for the variance components is strongly asymmetric. You could probably still generate a (asymmetric) CI by bootstrapping the variance estimates via merTools, but in the end I think it's much more straightforward to simply estimate your model with Stan / Jags or Inla.

Comment: *"This output does not give the residual variance, as I was used from the outputs"* This part is a bit off track and seems like a second question hidden inside a question about estimating the error of estimates of the variance of random effects. The residual variance is not relevant for this.

Answer (score 1):

Residual variance only makes sense when the distribution of the data is Gaussian (see Stroup, 2012 for examples). For non-Gaussian data, in your case Poisson, Nakagawa and Schielzeth or Nakagawa et al. (2017) try to generalize some of those ideas to other distributions (Poisson, Negative Binomial) by using approximations (i.e., Delta method). As such, what you are interested in is the variance of the approximation, or the variance of a function of a variance component. Like Florian mentioned, you can get those using Bayesian methods by looking at the posterior standard deviation of the parameters estimated. Also, when the distribution of the data is assumed to be Poisson, the dispersion parameter is set to $\omega=1$. I have included an example using simulated data and JAGS below.

```
n      = 1000
beta0  = 2  
beta1  = 1  
x      = rnorm(n)  
mu     = beta0*1 + beta1*x 
lambda = exp(mu)  
y      = rpois(n, lambda)  

modelcode = textConnection('model{
    # Likelihood
    for(i in 1:n){
        y[i]      ~ dpois(lambda[i]) # Poisson likelihood
        lambda[i] <- exp(mu[i])      # lambda from linear predictor
        mu[i]     <- inprod(beta[],X[i,]) # linear predictor
    }     
    # Priors 
    beta ~ dmnorm(mubeta,taubeta)  # prior for the regression coefficients
    tau <- log(1/exp(beta[1]) + 1) # the value you are after
}')

datalist = list(X = cbind(1, x),  
                y = y,  
                n = n,
                mubeta = c(0, 0),
                taubeta = diag(0.001, 2))
library(rjags)
model1 = jags.model(modelcode,  data = datalist)
output = coda.samples(model = model1, variable.names = c("beta", 'tau'),
                      n.iter = 1e4)
```

The relevant part of the output

```
 > summary(output)

 Iterations = 1001:11000
 Thinning interval = 1 
 Number of chains = 1 
 Sample size per chain = 10000 

 1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable, 
  plus standard error of the mean:

           Mean       SD  Naive SE Time-series SE
 beta[1] 2.0076 0.012982 1.298e-04      5.120e-04
 beta[2] 0.9933 0.010197 1.020e-04      4.155e-04
 tau     0.1260 0.001537 1.537e-05      6.063e-05
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: An alternative to using a Bayesian posterior distribution is to estimate the sample variance/error based on an estimate of the Fisher matrix.